# check if the page is HTML page in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code in python for Web crawler. I want to check if the page I am about to crawl is a HTML page and not page like .pdf/.doc/.docx etc.. I do not want to check it with extension .html as asp,aspx, or pages like http://bing.com/travel/ do not .html extensions explicitly but they are html pages. Is there any good way in python?

Comment: MIME-types are a good bet, I think.

Comment: Without loading any page data? Sounds hard. Otherwise, why not just check the `content-type`, or read the first few bytes and see if it looks like html? (starts with a `<DOCTYPE>` or `<html>`, for instance)

Comment: It is ok to load any page data. I just tried regular expression .*<.*html.*>.*" to check first few bytes as page can be <!DOCTYPE html>... or <html> but ra.match just goes in infinite loop for some pages.

Comment: How accurate do you want to be? You could choose to trust the content-type header or not. You could try to parse the HTML, or not. There is no "right" way to do this, it depends on how accurate/fast you want the HTML check to actually be.

Comment: I would prefer something that would work accurately. Without content read if I can do it it will be better.

Answer (score 5):

This gets the header only from the server:

```
import urllib2
url = 'http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.0/testing/linux-3.7-rc6.tar.bz2'
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.get_method = lambda: 'HEAD'
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
content_type = response.headers.getheader('Content-Type')
print(content_type)
```

prints

```
application/x-bzip2
```

From which you could conclude this is not HTML. You could use

```
'html' in content_type
```

to programmatically test if the content is HTML (or possibly XHTML).
If you wanted to be even more sure the content is HTML you could download the contents and try to parse it with an HTML parser like [lxml](http://lxml.de/) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4).

Beware of using `requests.get` like this:

```
import requests
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.headers['content-type'])
```

This takes a long time and my network monitor shows a sustained load leading me to believe this is downloading the entire file, not just the header.

On the other hand,

```
import requests
r = requests.head(url)
print(r.headers['content-type'])
```

gets the header only.

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother with what the standard library throws at you but, rather try [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get("http://www.google.com")
>>> r.headers['content-type']
    'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'
```